# How to sort files into Folders by years and months?

Tags: c#, xml, date, sorting

I have a program that will save files in `.xml` format and have manually added the date when the file is created with `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss")`. An example is like this **Scan 2013-07-15 11-13-31**. I would then need to sort these files that will be generated into folders in the directory of **C:\Users\name\Documents\Scan Archive** by years and months.

- Is this naming convention on the file good to do this sorting?
- How do I start coding for this to sort it into 
  **C:\Users\name\Documents\Scan Archive\2013** and
  **C:\Users\name\Documents\Scan Archive\2013\Jaunuary** and so forth.

Comment: I would recommend you use `01` instead of `January`, so if you want to do sorting in explorer then it is in chronological order, not numerical.

Comment: won't it be easier if  you save files in the folders in the following hierarchy at the first instance.Year-->Month-->Date-->Time

Comment: I need it to be in the archive folder for at least 1 month then moving the file into their respective subfolders after that. I'm unsure how to really approach this thou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String GetDirectoryName(DateTime time, String rootpath)
{
    String year = String.Format("{0:yyyy}", time);
    String month = String.Format("{0:MM}", time) + String.Format("{0:MMM}", time);
    String day = String.Format("{0:dd}", time);
    String filepath = Path.Combine(rootpath, "y" + year);
    filepath = Path.Combine(filepath, "m" + month);
    filepath = Path.Combine(filepath, "d" + day);
    return filepath;
}
```

This creates a directory path given a rootpath (such as **C:\users\name\Documents\Scan Archive**) and a `DateTime`.  You'd use the date referenced by your file's name.  Just parse out the file name into a `DateTime`.

As others have said in comments, don't use the name of the month unless its after some numeric values. I'd leave it out entirely as I find it slightly verbose.

Its easy to tack a file name onto the end of this path, and create all required directories when creating the file.  Problem solved!

Edit:
To create directories while creating some new file:

```
string dirpath = GetDirectoryName(date, "C:\Users\Name");
Directory.CreateDirectory(dirpath);
string filePpath = Path.combine(dirpath,"myfilename.txt");
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filePath);
info.Create().Close();
```

Comment: Thanks alot! now time for me to decipher what does what haha.

Comment: Hi I have used your code and it gave me the ideal string location that I wanted, however, When i executed File.move or File.copy, It did not create the subfolders like stated in the string. How should i do this?

Comment: Added an example for how to use the code.  I was mistaken. Calling file.create will not automatically create parent directories.